# Pb to detect random JS error, window.onerror doesn't show line number in a UIWebView (phonegap) - undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, uiwebview, undefined

I have some user complaining about a bug I can't reproduce. I want to send the error to my server each time they get a JS error. So I use the gobal onerror event, but unfortunately, the line number is not specified in phonegap (it's working correctly in safari) :

window.onerror=function(msg, url, line){ 
 alert('An error has occurred: '+msg+'line: '+line);//the line number and url are "undefined" 
 return true; 
}

How do you do to handle JS Runtime errors ?